# orientdb slow distributed etl import

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I have an ETL that looks something like below, except we are pulling 8 fields from the mysql and have 8 vertex classes, and 7 edge classes.

```
{
      "config": {
        "parallel": true
      },
      "extractor": {
        "jdbc": {
          "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
          "url": "jdbc:mysql://<some IP>/car_database",
          "userName": "admin",
          "userPassword": "admin",
          "query": "select uid, type, color, age from car_info;",
          "fetchSize": -2147483648
        }
      },
      "transformers": [
        {
          "vertex": {
            "class": "Car"
          }
        },
        {
          "field": {
            "fieldName": "value",
            "expression": "uid"
          }
        },
        {
          "edge": {
            "class": "HasType",
            "lookup": "Type.value",
            "joinFieldName": "type",
            "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
          }
        },
        {
          "edge": {
            "class": "HasColor",
            "lookup": "Color.value",
            "joinFieldName": "color",
            "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
          }
        },
        {
          "edge": {
            "class": "HasAge",
            "lookup": "Age.value",
            "joinFieldName": "age",
            "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
          }
        },
        {
          "field": {
            "fieldNames" : [
              "uid",
              "type",
              "color",
              "age"
            ],
            "operation": "remove"
          }
        }
      ],
      "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
          "dbURL": "remote:<some IP >/CarGraph",
          "dbType": "graph",
          "txUseLog": false,
          "wal": false,
          "tx": false,
          "batchCommit": 1000,
          "classes": [
            {
              "name": "Car",
              "extends": "V"
            },
             {
                "name": "Type",
                "extends": "V"
              },
              {
                "name": "HasType",
                "extends": "E"
              },
              {
                "name": "Color",
                "extends": "V"
              },
              {
                "name": "HasColor",
                "extends": "E"
              },
              {
                "name": "Age",
                "extends": "V"
              },
              {
                "name": "HasAge",
                "extends": "E"
              }
          ],
          "indexes": [
            {
              "class": "Car",
              "fields": [
                "value:string"
              ],
              "type": "UNIQUE"
            },
            {
              "class": "Type",
              "fields": [
                "value:string"
              ],
              "type": "UNIQUE"
            },
            {
              "class": "Color",
              "fields": [
                "value:string"
              ],
              "type": "UNIQUE"
            },
            {
              "class": "Age",
              "fields": [
                "value:string"
              ],
              "type": "UNIQUE"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is my default-distributed-db-cofig file:

```
{
  "autoDeploy": true,
  "hotAlignment": false,
  "executionMode": "undefined",
  "readQuorum": 1,
  "writeQuorum": 1,
  "failureAvailableNodesLessQuorum": false,
  "readYourWrites": true,
  "servers": {
    "*": "master"
  },
  "clusters": {
    "internal": {
    },
    "index": {
    },
    "*": {
      "servers": ["<NEW_NODE>"]
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement an orient cluster, currently with 2 nodes on separate servers. When I run the import on one of the graph boxes (only 200 rows from our current QA environment, prod will be 35 million plus), I am seeing load times of 1-3 nodes a second, even with quorum set to 1. I have tried 5-6 different combinations, toggling parallels, quorum values, different server set ups, but as long as the loader points to a remote db it is just really slow.

The same etl runs 1500-2000/s on my local box, into a plocal graph.

The fastest way I have found to run the import with the loader pointing to a plocal graph. Then once it finishes restart the servers as distributed and allow the 2 nodes to sync.

Is there something I'm missing, or some server config that could cause the import to be so slow?
Orient version 2.1.6.

Comment: remote + distributed are much slower than sigle plocal instance, so it makes sense to me.

Comment: @Lvca From 1000-2000 per second down to 1-3 nodes per second? Ouch, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: 1-3 per second it's absolutely not normal. It should be about 3k/sec with 3 nodes. Could you try with parallel and v2.1.7?

Comment: We are going to add another node today, and try a few imports with 2.1.8.